# How can I get Vagrant to open a browser on a URL after starting in OSX

Tags: vagrant

I want Vagrant to open the site specific to the box after starting. How can I make this happen?

Comment: not clear - you want the browser to run from mac os ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I want vagrant to open a url on my host OS as the last step on running `vagrant up`.

Answer (score 5):

Vagrantfile is a ruby script so you can call any command from the file, but it will run the command immediately and in any occasion.

Then, if you want to run after the box is started, you can use the [vagrant trigger plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) and do something like

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  .....
  config.trigger.after :up do
    system("open", "http://stackoverflow.com/")
  end
end
```

Comment: // , Ended up with this on an Ubuntu 16.04 box even after installing the `vagrant-triggers` plugin: `==> default: Running triggers after up...
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (Kubunutu 18LTS) the following worked great:

```
config.trigger.after [:up] do |trigger|
  trigger.name = "Open default browser"
  if Vagrant::Util::Platform.linux?
    trigger.run = {inline: "bash -c 'xdg-open http://#{configure['BOX_IP']}'"}
  end
end
```

It is also possible to check for other host platforms like this:

```
# Check for Windows
Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?

# Check for MacOS
Vagrant::Util::Platform.darwin?
```

With Vagrant 2.2.5 the triggers work out of the box. No additional plugin is required.